# Invert colors in SVG programmatically

Tags: python, svg, image-processing

I'm trying to write a script that will help me to prepare files for DIY PCBs production. It needs to invert colors of some vector image files like one in the attached image.
How can I transform this svg-image into the negative in a script. Preferably with Python or JS but I will study every opportunity.

Update:

My goal is to get a pdf file with a few images like this some of which are inverted or mirrored and with the border a bit enlarged. I always make this files with vector editor and it works fine for me. I need to keep it vectorized because I need the best printing quality with no smoothness. CSS invert() filter does exactly what I need but how can I save it again in a vector image format? Maybe it's possible to gather all the files I need on a web page and save it as a PDF? But again, I'd prefer it to be done automatically.

Image processing libraries I've seen work only with raster images.

Here is an example of image I want to process:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DBboHKNWkm_LRvJCoizJBP9UZcoZkLkZ/view?usp=sharing

[image: Image I need to get color inverted]

Comment: Take this opportunity and learn image processing in python or JS. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. See [tour] and [ask]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/invert

Comment: what's the goal? G-code? or a printout, the toner of which you transfer onto a blank pcb for etching? -- how about you don't write a program for this, but use an ***editor program*** for SVG or raster images?

Comment: Why have you shared a PNG (raster) if you have an SVG and want to keep an SVG as output? Wouldn't it be better to share your SVG - with Dropbox or Google Drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many viewers can reverse the rendered view the big issue is how can that be used with some accurate output, the high resolution (600dpi) "print to pdf image" will still be the source colors (not inverted).

[image]

The issue is that the SVG will be monochrome when converted thus the foreground needs to be ink.

[image]

If you try to reverse in a PDF the vector shape outlines get distorted.
[image]

The best programmable route will be via a programmable raster graphics application or a vector one like Inkscape/Krita.

or reprogram the colours in a programable text editor driven by commands

[image]

From a programming aspect the clue in this sample is the outline is the only object with `"fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5` in its definition. Otherwise it covers all the prior objects !!

```
<g        id="g2186"><path          d="M 0.1,141.89 V 13.44 H 175.86999 V 141.89 H 0.1"          style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"          id="path2188" /></g>
```

As it is the last object it needs to to be moved to first object (after the header, before ...ID"g10"...). The fill can be set to `#000000` the colour change to all other groups will then be seen in contrast and can be done by similar find and replace as shown.

Comment: The last picture looks very close to what I need. Thank you for your attempt. As I understand, you just open the file in a text editor and chenge the colors of fills and strokes, right?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your svg image into png first. you can do this using:

```
pip3 install svglib
```

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM

drawing = svg2rlg('image.svg')
renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, 'image.png', fmt='PNG')
```

and then use Pillow to turn your file into negative:

```
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps    

image = Image.open('image.png')

inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(image)

inverted_image.save('negative_image.png')
```

Comment: I'd prefer to keep it in a vector format